# How to make an App script to view edit history on Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

My Google sheet data is too large so  my view edit history doesnt work , so is there a way where i can make a script to view history on a certain page of that sheet

I was trying to get a tool by which can see edit history of my sheet on a addon or app script

Answer (score 0):

You can use the advanced Drive service (which is a wrapper for the Drive API v2) and list the revisions of a file.

```
function listFileRevisions(fileId) {
  let response = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  console.log(response.items)
}
```

You'll first have to activate this service, so follow this little guide if you've never done it before: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

You can see here what the response will look like: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list?#response